# Difference between Equality & Object Equality

Tags: equality

This question may be a bit vague but can anyone give me a full explanation on what is the 
difference between reference equality and object equality?

Comment: Without a language you probably won't get a good answer.  Googling it will give better results.

Comment: Homework dump question #2 for this poster.  Better that you should do your own d@mn homework than to keep dumping your assignment questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Object Oriented Languages like Java, objects are data structures that contain both state and behavior.  An object's state is determined by the value or values of it's internal data fields and its behavior is determined by the methods (functions or procedures) that are defined for the object (and which usually operate on the object's internal fields -- but not necessarily).  Objects are always accessed by reference.  That is, a variable holds a pointer to the memory location of the object.

Thus, objects may possess both value and location.

**Equality** tests whether two objects possess the same "value" (defined by the internal state of the objects), i.e. "do these two objects have the same value?"

**Identity** tests whether two -references- to an object are the same, i.e. "are these two objects the same object (at the same place in memory)?"

You'll notice that it is thus possible for objects to have the exact same value but different identities if they are separate structures in different memory locations.  It is never possible for two object references to have the same identity (i.e., referring to the same data structure in memory) but different values.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, reference equality would indicate that the two pointers point to the same address.  Object equality would be two objects in different areas of memory that have the same data.

It's the difference between saying that two pointers both point to the same object, and that two objects are exact copies of each other.